# Jenkins dynamic parameters plugin (based on previously selected parameter value) + shell support

Tags: dynamic, groovy, parameters, jenkins

I was wondering, does anyone know if there is plugin exists for Jenkins that 
lets me build with parameters and one parameter's choices are based on the selection of previous parameter's choices AND also lets me use Groovy/shell/or someone other scripting language to set those parameters (because I would like to be able to load parameters from a server or some other external source)?

EDIT:

****I'll demonstrate through an example: 


Choice Parameter #1 values:  
 
    a,b,c,d  
  
 
Choice Parameter #2 values:  
  
 
    Get values from #1,

   if a=>g,if b=>g, c=>x,  
  
 
Choice Parameter #3 value:  
 
  Get values from #2, 
   if g=>l,if x=>q
etc.  
 
 
 
AND I want to be able to set each Parameter box externally (i.e. load it from a file and/or server)****

Comment: It's totally unclear, what do you want to achieve. Please, ask more specific question. For example what did you mean, saying "build with parameters"?

Comment: I'll demonstrate through an example: Choice Parameter #1 values: a,b,c,d
Choice Parameter #2 values: Get values from #1, if a=>g,if b=>g, c=>x, AND I want to be able to set each Parameter box externally (i.e. load it from a file and/or server)